# RegEx to return string between 2 specific characters?

Tags: regex

Can you please advise on how to return a string between 2 specific characters?

#### Example

> `http://sds.01/create/http/capital/870745800/create/period_1_1364871116_438861511.ssa`

I want to return : 1364871116_438861511, which is between "period_1_" AND ".ssa"

Answer (score 5):

Use this regex:

```
period_1_(.*)\.ssa
```

For example, in Perl you would extract it like this:

```
my ($substr) = ($string =~ /period_1_(.*)\.ssa/);
```

For Python, use this code:

```
m = re.match(r"period_1_(.*)\.ssa", my_long_string)
print m.group(1)
```

Last print will print string you are looking for (if there is a match).

Comment: Thanks mvp, but when I tested it using this RegEx tester: http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/regex-tester.html It returns "period_1_1364871116_438861511.ssa" and not "1364871116_438861511"

Comment: Which language you are using? I have tried my Perl code, and it does work. For regex tests online, I prefer http://RegexPlanet.com, [this link](http://fiddle.re/e2be6) proves that it works for Java for example (see `group(1)`)

Comment: Python and/or .JS, I think. I'm using this in XBMC, if you're familiar with it. I'm not a programmer, so I just need a reg expression that returns just "1364871116_438861511". Thanks for your help bro!

Comment: Use this link and click on Python test: http://fiddle.re/e2be6 it shows that you should use `findAll()` or `group(1)` methods to get what you want.

Comment: Edited answer to add Python example

Comment: use fidnAll() where?...that can't be right! Let me give an example of what works and what I'm looking for: This RegEx ([\.\d]+) will return the IP Address in this expression address=http://192.168.1.7 I don't use findAll All I need is the REG Expression. TXH

Comment: Look at my Python example which I added in the question - it certainly does work

Comment: Yes, I can see that it works in your example and mine! what doesn't it work using my reg tester? any idea? THX MAN!

Comment: One more thing..will this return this [u'1364884934_2031539073'] OR 1364884934_2031539073? What I need is the later, no test or any additional character. THX

Comment: It should return just the string when you print it. `u'xxx'` is only Python decoration for Unicode strings.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't see any link or button to click!

Comment: @PaulM: See [the **How do I ask questions?** section](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) of the Super User FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions) –– “When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the **accepted answer** by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.”  If you do that, you and the author of the answer (mvp) both benefit.  After you have earned some [reputation](http://superuser.com/faq#reputation), you can also [vote up](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) helpful answers by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks Scott, BUT I don't see what you're talking about...I only see add comments and answer your question!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=period_1_)(.*)(?=.ssa)
```

This extracts the part between "period_1_" and ".ssa".

https://regexr.com/3jtbm